# What is causing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Tags: java, maven, jackson

Looking around at similar posts for this error, it seems that the issue comes from having incompatible versions of the same dependency. I have one project that calls a class from another, thus I have two separate pom.xml's, but both have the same version of the jackson dependency so I'm not sure what is causing this error. Here are my two pom.xml's:

pom.xml #1

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.bingads</groupId>
    <version>12.13.3</version>
    <name>Bing Ads Java SDK</name>
    <description>The Bing Ads Java SDK is a library improving developer experience when working with the Bing Ads services by providing high-level access to features such as Bulk API, OAuth Authorization and SOAP API.</description>
    <url>https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-Java-SDK</url>


    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jcsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcsv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>${http.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${http.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.bingads</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft.bingads</artifactId>
             <version>12.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cxf.version>3.3.2</cxf.version>
        <http.version>4.5.3</http.version>
    </properties>
    <artifactId>microsoft.bingads</artifactId>
</project>
```

and pom.xml #2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.google.api-ads.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>adwords-axis-examples</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.0</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>AdWords Examples using Axis</name>
  <description>
    This project contains examples of using the Ads APIs client library for Java
    with AdWords and the Apache Axis framework. Please see the README file for
    more information about how to use the library.
  </description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <smokeMainClass>adwords.axis.v201809.basicoperations.GetCampaigns</smokeMainClass>
  </properties>


<dependencies>


  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- Ads client library dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
      <artifactId>ads-lib</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
      <artifactId>adwords-axis</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Third party dependencies -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core --><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->




    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
      <version>1.48</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Configuration to use log4j for logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>smoketest</id>
      <properties>
        <exec.mainClass>${smokeMainClass}</exec.mainClass>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

When running each class separately, they both compile and run as intended, but when I call b.foo() from class a, I get the error in the title. Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: can you provide a full stack trace of the exception you receive? most probably the issue is not in your code, but in one of the libraries your project depends on; presumably one of googles or poi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked around deeper through some of the dependencies and found that one was using a lower version of Jackson that you couldn't see on the surface. So if you have this problem and you're using Eclipse, view your pom.XML through the Dependencies Hierarchy view and you should be able to see where the incompatibility comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the parent module and other child modules integration using maven, and add the dependency in parent module so that should be consider by both child module.